# Python - regex to keep only words with textual characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to have a regex in my Python program to keep only words that contain alphabetical text characters (i.e. no special characters such as dots, commas, :, ! etc.)

I am using this code to get the words from a text file:

```
find_words = re.compile(r'\w+').findall
```

The problem with this regular expression is that for input like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----
Proc-Type: 2001,MIC-CLEAR
Originator-Name: webmaster@www.sec.gov
Originator-Key-Asymmetric:
 MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen
 TWSM7vrzLADbmYQaionwg5sDW3P6oaM5D3tdezXMm7z1T+B+twIDAQAB
MIC-Info: RSA-MD5,RSA,
 U6u1HjX9A2VnveGmx3CbhhgTr7o+NJWodWNJQjg1aSLDkLnJwruLq9hBBcqxouFq
 NY7xtb92dCTfvEjdmkDrUw==

0001393311-11-000011.txt : 20110301
0001393311-11-000011.hdr.sgml : 20110301
20110301164350
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001393311-11-000011
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  10-K
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      16
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20101231
FILED AS OF DATE:       20110301
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20110301

FILER:
```

I get output like this:

```
begin
privacy
enhanced
message
proc
type
2001
mic
clear
originator
name
webmaster
www
sec
gov
originator
key
asymmetric
mfgwcgyevqgbaqicaf8dsgawrwjaw2snkk9avtbzyzmr6agjlwyk3xmzv3dtinen
twsm7vrzladbmyqaionwg5sdw3p6oam5d3tdezxmm7z1t
b
twidaqab
mic
info
rsa
md5
rsa
u6u1hjx9a2vnvegmx3cbhhgtr7o
njwodwnjqjg1asldklnjwrulq9hbbcqxoufq
ny7xtb92dctfvejdmkdruw
0001393311
11
000011
txt
20110301
0001393311
11
000011
hdr
sgml
```

which is not what I want because

A) it does not keep words that I want it to keep such as `"Accession", "Number"` etc., and it also keeps stuff like `mfgwcgyevqgbaqicaf8dsgawrwjaw2snkk9avtbzyzmr6agjlwyk3xmzv3dtinen` which I don't want to keep because of the numbers in the word, and it also keeps `0001393311` etc. which I don't want to keep.

Any ideas on how to get the `words` that I want ? (i.e. to contain only alphabetical characters).

Comment: you mean this `r'\b[A-Za-z]+\b'` ?

Comment: If I have *psa:DaytonNeedmoreRoadMember* this gives me two words *psa*
and *daytonneedmoreroadmember* but I want none because it is not valid

Comment: try `r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)'`

Comment: @adrCoder what's your criteria of being valid? maybe you can start from formalizing this first.

Comment: @adrCoder - if "Number:" contains a valid word (Number), then why wouldn't "psa:DaytonNeedmoreRoadMember" (psa)?  Intuitively, one might easily see why, but computers do not do things intuitively, you must from your intuitive understanding, extract the precise rules to give to the computer program.

Comment: I wouldn't like to keep any of the words in *psa:DaytonNeedmoreRoadMember* because I have many tags like these (which I could not remove with BeautifulSoup). These tags are generated from content which is to be read by specific software. So I would like to keep the word "Number" but not any of the *psa:DaytonNeedmoreRoadMember*

Comment: @AvinashRaj your regex is the closest to what I want. Is it possible that I keep words such as `Number` from `Number:` but none of `psa:DaytonNeedmoreRoadMember` . I suppose if after the ` you have character it should not accept. Thanks

Comment: @adrCoder you mean this https://regex101.com/r/dG2hY5/2 ?

Comment: Hi @AvinashRaj if you write your two answers (handling the two different cases) I will accept it since it is the closer to what I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you actually need to use a negative look-behind assertion.

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)|(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=:(?!\S))
```

- `(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)` matches the exact word which must contain alphabets.
- `|` OR
- `(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=:(?!\S))` One or more word characters which must be followed by a colon which in-turn not followed by a non-space character. You could use `(?=:\s)` pattern instead of `(?=:(?!\S))` also.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dG2hY5/3)

Answer (score 3):

```
re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", string):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract words separated with non-letters, you can use `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b` regex (outputs `Originator` and `Name` from `Originator-Name:`).

If you want to limit to the entities that are most likely to be words, I'd suggest something like:

`(?<![.-])\b([a-z]{2,}|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+|[A-Z]{2,})\b(?!\.|@|\-)`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/lO8oV8/1). This regex will limit the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
(?<=^|\P{L})\p{L}+(?=\P{L}|$)
```

or, to avoid variable lookbehind:

```
(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?=\P{L}|$)
```

where:

```
\p{L} means any letter (unicode)
\P{L} is the opposite of \p{L} ie. NOT a letter
```

Comment: *find_words = re.compile(r'(?<=^|\PL)\pL+(?=\PL|$)').findall* throws an error     *raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern* . Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @adrCoder: Not sure for Python, but you may try with `\p{L}` instead of `\pL`, see my edit.

Comment: Still gives the same error     `raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern` but I will try to see if I can make it work. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: it compiles but returns no words... I am calling `find_words = re.compile(r'(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?=\P{L}|$)').findall` as `for word in find_words(line.lower()):` by the way..

Comment: @adrCoder: I don't know well python syntax, but isn't it: `find_words = re.findall(r'(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?=\P{L}|$)', input_string)`?